# AWS Glue ETL: Reading huge JSON file format to process but, got OutOfMemory Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

I am working on AWS-Glue ETL part for reading huge json file (only test 1 file and around 9 GB.) to work in ETL process but, I got an error from AWS Glue of `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` after running and processing for a while

My code and flow is so simple as

```
df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json(f"s3/raw_path") 
// ...
// and write to be as source_df to other object in s3 
df.write.json(f"s3/source_path", lineSep=",\n")
```

In error/log It seems likes It failed and terminated container since reading this huge file. I have already tried to upgrade worker type to be `G1.X` with a sample number of worker node, however, I just would like to ask and find another solution that does not look like vertical scaling as increasing resources

I am so new in this area and service so, wanna optimize cost and time as low as possible :-)

Thank you alls in advance

Comment: Can you repartition your dataframe to see if it works? something like df=df.repartition(20)

Comment: I think the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63353541/load-json-file-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) could be useful for you?

Comment: I have not seen the number of partitions for the entire process now, should I add more number to repartition? @PrabhakarReddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking into Glue and Spark, I found that to get the benefit of parallelism processing across multiple executors, for my case - I split the (large) file into multiple smaller files and it worked! The files are distributed to multiple executors.