# Load JSON file: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, json, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I have a problem that I am trying to read a JSON file that can be very large and it gives me a memory error because everything I find is loaded directly into an array instead of being able to access object by object.

My code is:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json"));

            JSONArray jsonObject = (JSONArray) obj;
            Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonObject.iterator();

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
               ...
            }
```

Everything I find does not allow me to load the items as I need them, does anyone know if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which library you are using for JSON parsing. For my experience, I suggest you to use the [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to accomplish this task. It has stream support to manage file and avoid to load all data in memory and then convert them into JSON. Jackson allows you to convert JSON data format into POJO.

If you need a short tutorial to view how to use it, you can follow [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-streaming-api) and [this link](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial).

Comment: I checked it initially, but the problem is that I need a POJO and the content of my JSON is variable

Comment: @JuanCarlosSerranoPérez Jackson is capable of handling variable JSON without using POJOs

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, this is best suited with **mmap files** (memory mapped files), where you can access file in memory which are much larger that available memory. It gives you the false feeling of complete file loaded in memory.

[Memory mapped filed in java](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/nio/memory-mapped-files-mappedbytebuffer/)

I am pretty sure that there should be some framework abstraction already built over mmap files to handle **json** files. I am just giving you a suggestion not the solution btw.